# How does Android os read id3 tags in MP3 files?

Tags: java, android, mp3, id3

I want to get and set the attributes of an id3 tag. Title, artist, album, composer etc. I did Google for help and found many 3rd party jars that I can use in my Android project to get and set the attributes. But I want to know a way to do it without using the 3rd party jar files. I'm sure there should be a way without me doing all the hard work. If not how does Android os itself gets the details when an MP3 file is added to the filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html)

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource("NeverGonnaGiveYouUp.mp3");
String album = 
   mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
```

Note that only limited set of tags is supported and access is read only

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would assume the function extractMetaData would get me the value. So is there also a method to set it? And if I do set it would it be updated in the actual file or just in the android database?

Comment: I'm sorry read only wouldn't work for me. I also need to modify the data.

Comment: That's why people use 3rd party libraries if they need to modify the tags. Standard Android API is read only.

Comment: Can't believe there isn't a utility in android itself that would allow me to modify the details. Which means I'll be forced to use the 3rd party jar file to achieve it. Thanks for the insight though.

Comment: I think this library is broken. It does not retrieve anything, not even `MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST`...? And it does not even provide `METADATA_KEY_COMMENT`. I've read long time ago that it was known to be broken in ICS, but I tested it now in KitKat, and it is also broken.